# How to put a scroll event on svg in d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I am developing a stack bar chart in d3 js.

My code structure is mentioned below:

```
<div id="frame1">
<div class = "header">
//code...  
</div>
<div class = "box">
//Here I am calling a JavaScript function which will develop a stack bar chart using svg.
</div>
</div>
```

I have set the property of box as 'auto' for 'overflow'.
So when the amount of data is huge, The box becomes a scroll panel.
I have given name to Y-axis.
The code for it is:

```
svg.append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  // this makes it easy to centre the text as the transform is applied to the anchor
  .attr("transform", "translate("+ -50 +","+redefineHeightForLabel()+")rotate(-90)")  // text is drawn off the screen top left, move down and out and rotate
  .text("Timings");
```

So if the amount of data is huge, then I have to scroll down in order to see the remaining data. But by doing this my label for Y - axis goes up.
So whenever I perform a scroll I want to put a event on svg in order to calculate the height for label .

Comment: can you share the svg structure / creation code? A fiddle or a working snippet would be even better.

Comment: `d3.select('.box').on('scroll', function() { /* update label inside svg */ }`)

Comment: @meetamit I had tried your solution earlier and it did not work. However I figure out the solution to the above problem.
I have put a scroll event on div tag and calling a function on that event and in the function, I am changing the parameter for labels